# Isomorphism of circulant graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Can circulant graphs be isomorphic to any non-circulant regular graph? 
I am trying to show uniqueness of a graph for a given independence polynomial and the graph I obtained is a circulant graph on 9 vertices.
My question is..
Does there exists any non circulant graph which is isomorphic to circulant graphs?

Comment: No. Isomorphic graphs have isomorphic automorphism groups.

Comment: Does it have a proof??Like,if we take a regular graph then it will be a circulant graph??

Comment: Regular graphs are not isomorphic to circulants as a rule.